# Check if URL in a XML is accessible

Tags: vb.net

With this code I am reading a XML-File that is on a server. In this XML-File are several links. I have to check them if they are accessible. For each link I add an item to a listview with a green background (accessible) or a red background (not accessible). The program is relatively slow.

```
Public Class frmMain

Private listFiles As New List(Of String())

Structure Infos
    Dim strText As String
    Dim TextBox As Control
    Dim Label As Label
End Structure

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Icon = My.Resources.internet_ok
    loadSettings()
End Sub

Private Sub loadSettings()
    Dim strPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Settings.txt")
    If Exists(strPath) = True Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(strPath)
            listFiles.Add(line.Split(CType(";", Char())))
        Next
        listFiles.Reverse()
        Dim iIndexText As Integer = 0
        Dim iIndexChecked As Integer = 0
        For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
            If control.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) = True Then
                control.Text = listFiles.Item(iIndexText)(0)
                iIndexText += 1
            End If
            If control.GetType Is GetType(CheckBox) = True Then
                DirectCast(control, CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(listFiles.Item(iIndexChecked)(1))
                iIndexChecked += 1
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Missing 'Settings.txt' !" & vbNewLine & "The Program will be closed now!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    lvOutput.Items.Clear()
    Dim selected = getSelected()
    For i As Integer = 0 To selected.Count - 1
        Dim infos As Infos = selected.Item(i)
        If checkURL(infos.strText) = True Then
            Dim txtBox As TextBox = CType(infos.TextBox, TextBox)
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Else
            Dim txtBox As TextBox = CType(infos.TextBox, TextBox)
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        txtLink1.Update : txtLink2.Update : txtLink3.Update : txtLink4.Update
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To selected.Count - 1
        Dim infos As Infos = selected.Item(i)
        Dim txtBox As TextBox = CType(infos.TextBox, TextBox)
        If txtBox.BackColor = Color.LightGreen Then
            Dim Label As Label = CType(infos.Label, Label)
            checkContent(infos.strText, Label.Text)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function getSelected() As List(Of Infos)
    Dim list As New List(Of Infos)
    If cbLink1.Checked = True Then
        Dim infos As New Infos() With {.strText = txtLink1.Text, .TextBox = txtLink1, .Label = lblPfad1}
        list.Add(infos)
    End If
    If cbLink2.Checked = True Then
        Dim infos As New Infos() With {.strText = txtLink2.Text, .TextBox = txtLink2, .Label = lblPfad2}
        list.Add(infos)
    End If
    If cbLink3.Checked = True Then
        Dim infos As New Infos() With {.strText = txtLink3.Text, .TextBox = txtLink3, .Label = lblPfad3}
        list.Add(infos)
    End If
    If cbLink4.Checked = True Then
        Dim infos As New Infos() With {.strText = txtLink4.Text, .TextBox = txtLink4, .Label = lblPfad4}
        list.Add(infos)
    End If
    Return list
End Function

Private Function checkURL(ByVal strURL As String) As Boolean
    If strURL.StartsWith("http") = False Then
        strURL = "http://" & strURL
    End If
    Try
        Dim webclient As New WebClient
        Dim strContent As String = webclient.DownloadString(strURL)
        If strContent.Contains("Error") = True Then
            Return False
        Else
            Dim response As WebResponse = Nothing
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
            response = request.GetResponse
            response.Close()
            Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub checkContent(ByVal strURL As String, ByVal strLabelPfad As String)
    File.CreateText(Application.StartupPath & "\Content.xml").Close()
    If strURL.StartsWith("http") = False Then
        strURL = "http://" & strURL
    End If

    Dim webclient As New WebClient
    webclient.DownloadFile(strURL, Application.StartupPath & "\Content.xml")
    Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(Application.StartupPath & "\Content.xml")
    Do While reader.Read
        If reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text Then
            Try
                Dim request As WebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(reader.Value), WebRequest)
                Dim response As WebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), WebResponse)
                response = request.GetResponse
                response.Close()
                lvOutput.Items.Add(strLabelPfad & " " & reader.Value).BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            Catch ex As Exception
                lvOutput.Items.Add(strLabelPfad & " " & reader.Value).BackColor = Color.Red
            End Try
            Application.DoEvents()
        End If
    Loop
    reader.Close()
    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\Content.xml")
End Sub

Private Sub cbLink1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbLink1.CheckedChanged
    If cbLink1.Checked = True Then
        txtLink1.Enabled = False
    Else
        txtLink1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cbLink2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbLink2.CheckedChanged
    If cbLink2.Checked = True Then
        txtLink2.Enabled = False
    Else
        txtLink2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cbLink3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbLink3.CheckedChanged
    If cbLink3.Checked = True Then
        txtLink3.Enabled = False
    Else
        txtLink3.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cbLink4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbLink4.CheckedChanged
    If cbLink4.Checked = True Then
        txtLink4.Enabled = False
    Else
        txtLink4.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\Settings.txt") = False Then
        Application.Exit()
    Else
        Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\Settings.txt")
        Dim fs As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\Settings.txt", FileMode.Create)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1}", txtLink1.Text, cbLink1.Checked))
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1}", txtLink2.Text, cbLink2.Checked))
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1}", txtLink3.Text, cbLink3.Checked))
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1}", txtLink4.Text, cbLink4.Checked))
        sw.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lvOutput_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvOutput.DoubleClick
    Dim strItemSelected() As String = lvOutput.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text.Split(CType(":", Char()))
    If strItemSelected(2).StartsWith("//") = True Then
        strItemSelected(2) = "http:" & strItemSelected(2)
    End If
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(strItemSelected(2), TextDataFormat.Text)
End Sub
End Class
```

I am not the best in English, it´s not my main language, so the code could be a little bit 'Denglisch' ;)
And yeah, I am relatively new to programming.

Comment: What do you mean by relatively slow?

Answer (score 1):

As first thing I should say that I am not a professional programmer, nor I have a knowledge of vb.net. My home platform is C# and I am just an enthusiast.

With this spoken I can give you only a few hints, which I could spot right away:

```
For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
    If control.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) = True Then
        control.Text = listFiles.Item(iIndexText)(0)
        iIndexText += 1
    End If
    If control.GetType Is GetType(CheckBox) = True Then
        DirectCast(control, CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(listFiles.Item(iIndexChecked)(1))
        iIndexChecked += 1
    End If
Next
```

This could use else statement. Because if it is `textBox`, it cannot be `checkBox`, right? So middle-lines might be like:

```
    ...
    iIndexText += 1
ElseIf control.GetType Is GetType(CheckBox) = True Then
    DirectCast(control, CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(listFiles.Item(iIndexChecked)(1))
    ...
```

---

Next what I see:

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    lvOutput.Items.Clear()
    Dim selected = getSelected()
    For i As Integer = 0 To selected.Count - 1
        Dim infos As Infos = selected.Item(i)
        If checkURL(infos.strText) = True Then
            Dim txtBox As TextBox = CType(infos.TextBox, TextBox)
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Else
            Dim txtBox As TextBox = CType(infos.TextBox, TextBox)
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
```

In both parts of `If ... Then ... Else` you define the same `txtBox`. You might want to move it next to definition of `Dim infos`. This way you will get only singe definition instead of two. You might also include next `for-loop` into the first one, because you only check for background color which you recently set. Thus final version might be

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    lvOutput.Items.Clear()
    Dim selected = getSelected()
    For i As Integer = 0 To selected.Count - 1
        Dim infos As Infos = selected.Item(i)
        Dim txtBox As TextBox = CType(infos.TextBox, TextBox)
        If checkURL(infos.strText) = True Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            Dim Label As Label = CType(infos.Label, Label)
            checkContent(infos.strText, Label.Text)
        Else
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        txtLink1.Update : txtLink2.Update : txtLink3.Update : txtLink4.Update
    Next
End Sub
```

Also (*but here I am really unsure, so proceed with caution*) you might move `txtLink1.Update : txtLink2.Update : txtLink3.Update : txtLink4.Update` after the `Next` right behind it. If I get this right, the aforementioned "update line" is updating background colors and other info and forcing redraw ([MSDN  definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.110).aspx)). This might suffice to do after all info about new colors is obtained.

---

Concerning methods `getSelected`, you might get somewhat simpler code with `foreach` iterator (however, I didn´t mange from top of my hat the issue with different labels for each `.Label`, so it is possible that this will not work):

```
Private Function getSelected() As List(Of Infos)
    Dim list As New List(Of Infos)
    For Each cbLinkX As CheckBox In Me.Controls
        If cbLinkX.Checked = True Then
            Dim infos As New Infos() With {.strText = cbLinkX.Text, .TextBox = cbLinkX, .Label = ??? }
            list.Add(infos)
        End If
    Next
    Return list
End Function
```

---

In methods `checkURL` and `checkContent` you are swallowing all exceptions. You might consider catching only those "URL-checking" related an letting the rest keep propagating (and possibly crashing) your code.

---

In methods `cbLinkX_CheckedChanged`, you are always changing `txtBoxX.Enabled` to oposite to `cbLinkX.Checked`, you might take advance of this as:

```
Private Sub cbLinkX_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbLinkX.CheckedChanged
    txtLinkX.Enabled = Not cbLinkX.Checked
End Sub
```

---

Doesn´t `frmMain_FormClosing` miss from `Else`-part a `Application.Exit()` command? If yes, then you can edit your method to save data, close `sw` and finally exit app outside an `if` statement. Also you should consider exiting apps with error codes - 0 usually means that app exited normally, non-zero usually means crash.

---

But again, those are only my suggestions and not necessary will be always working, so definitely make backup prior any edit. And do only one edit at a time, no matter how small and trivial it might appear. You would be surprised how trivial tasks might sometimes hilariously fail ;-)

Anyway, good luck :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with not being a professional. I'd say you did pretty good.